# при выборе значения из select это значение сохраняется в localStorage, но при перезагрузки вытащить это значение в setOption я не могу, в чем ошибка?

Tags: reactjs, localstorage, state

```
export function MainPage() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState<Cat[]>([]);
  const [option, setOption] = useState<number>(
  Number(localStorage.getItem('option')));

useEffect(() => {
  if(Number(localStorage.getItem('option'))) {
    setOption(option)
  }
  localStorage.setItem('option', JSON.stringify(option));
},[option])

  useEffect(() => {
    const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("someData");
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не можете? Возможно, у вас где то ниже по коду идет установка дефольного значения? И вот это вообще странно, если вы сохраняете число `JSON.stringify(option)`. Проверьте, в каком виде у вас данные лежат в localStorage